# how to download audio file from firebase storage and save them (the files) to a folder in external storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, storage

any possible solution please
I want to create a music player for specific songs save in external storage of the device

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have solve the problem bro using a an API for music player